# jQuery Datepicker date range populates inline calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to get the jQuery datepicker date range fields to highlight the selected dates an inline calendar. So far I have gotten the inline calendar to get the selected dates to populate 2 different fields, `date1` and `date2`. I just need the selected date ranges to highlight the selected dates inside the calendar.

I have created a jsfiddle here ( [Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Marcus_Dev/qysnhLoo/3/) )

I have tried the jQuery alternate field method but with no success, any help would be appreciated!

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: Date Picker]

Comment: Your code works, you're just missing an style for `.dp-highlight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

With your extra comments I better understand what you are trying to do.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/hehkh6v3/).

Brief summary:

- `onSelect()` is the best way to handle a date selection, and it is passed the selected date as a string, so I removed your `.on()` handlers and the `getDate()` function.
- Save the start/end dates when they are selected;
- Refresh your inline datepicker with `$('#datepicker').datepicker('refresh');` when a start/end is selected, so that your `beforeShowDay()` is called and can repaint the calendar using those selected dates.  It will have also fired on initialisation of the inline datepicker but as no dates were selected at that stage it did nothing.
- Simplify the test you had in `beforeShowDay()` to add a class to days between start and end, inclusive.  I understand you might want a bit more than this (eg maybe highlight the start date when it is all that is selected) but this is the simplest case that demonstrates a working example.
- Added basic styling for your `.dp-highlight` class, had to add more specificity to make sure it overrides the default datepicker styling.
- I also removed a few things to keep it simple:

  - extra inputs under inline datepicker, I realise you maybe need them for the next step but that's not directly related to this problem;
  - inline datepicker `onSelect` code, again not directly related to this problem;

Comment: Thanks for your help but what I'm trying to do is get the date range from my original fiddle and append that to the inline calendar (so the dates selected from the date range are highlighted in the calendar). Does that make more sense?

Comment: Not much :-) `So far I have gotten the inline calendar to get the selected dates to populate 2 different fields`.  OK, so select 2 dates on the inline calendar and highlight the range?  But then: `I just need the selected date ranges to highlight the selected dates inside the calendar.` Now we are switching to another set of datepicker inputs?  Sorry, don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've updated my question with an image. Thanks for helping me clear things up! Just looking for the date range fields to get the inline calendar to highlight the selected dates.